# Проблемы с функцией scanf и циклом while

Tags: c

Код:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>


void get_num ( int *pi )
{
    printf("Введите число: ");
    scanf("%d\n", pi);
}


int main ( void )
{
    int i = 1;
    
    while ( i != 0 )
    {
        get_num(&i);
        printf("Ваше число: %d\n", i);
    }

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Вывод:

```
user@user:~$ ./a.out 
Введите число: 1 
2
Ваше число: 1
Введите число: 3
Ваше число: 2
Введите число: 4
Ваше число: 3
Введите число: a
Введите число: Ваше число: 4
Введите число: Ваше число: 4
Введите число: Ваше число: 4
Введите число: Ваше число: 4
Введите число: Ваше число: 4
Введите число: Ваше число: 4
...
```

После ввода числа предполагался его вывод, но выводится число, введенное в прошлый раз, а при вводе букв возникает бесконечный вывод. Почему такое происходит?

Answer (score 1):

Не так хорош в *C*, но, мне кажется основная причина, почему у вас выводится предыдущее число - это *escape символ* или *new line* кому как удобней: `\n`.

*Почему бесконечный цикл?*, ответ, как мне кажется это потому что, когда вы вводите нецифровой символ то оператор ввода `scanf %d` не может спарсить веденный символ как целое число и он оставляет его в буфере.Так что при следующей итерацией цикла `while`,он считывает точно такой же символ еще раз, повторно.

Answer (score 1):

Потому что вы передали [`scanf`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf) строку формата с пробельным символом:

```cpp
scanf("%d\n", pi);
//       ^^
```

> Любой отдельный символ пробела в строке формата потребляет все
> доступные последовательные символы пробела из входных данных
> (определяется как если бы вызывался
> [`isspace`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/isspace) в
> цикле). Обратите внимание, что нет никакой разницы между `"\n"`, `" "`, `"\t\t"` или другими пробелами в строке формата.
>
> Первый символ, если таковой имеется, после этой использованной
> последовательности остается непрочитанным

То есть первый вызов `scanf` будет ожидать число, последовательность пробелов, а потом любой символ (этот символ останется непрочитанным).

Второй вызов будет ожидать то же самое, но в качестве ввода ему будет передан непрочитанный символ с первой итерации. И если он не может быть преобразован в число, произойдёт сбой сопоставления.

В случае сбоя символ так и останется непрочитанным, и на следующей итерации произойдёт то же самое. Поэтому ввод буквы приводит к зацикливанию

Answer (score 1):

Наверное Вы бы хотели получить вот такое поведение вашей программы:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


int get_num ( int *pi )
{
    printf("Введите число: ");
    return scanf("%d", pi);
}


int main ( void )
{
    int i = 1, c = 0;

    do
    {
        if ( get_num(&i) != 0)
            printf("Ваше число: %d\n", i);
    
        while ((c = getchar() != '\n') && c != EOF){}
    } while ( i != 0 );

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: Только не мешает еще сделать проверки на EOF

Comment: @avp Добавил проверку на EOF

Comment: Я бы выходил из `do { ...} while(...);` по `c == EOF`.